# brew services start nginx

Tags: nginx, homebrew

sudo brew services start nginx

Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` exited with 37.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.